# How does kmeans know how to cluster documents when we only feed it tfidf vectors of individual words?

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, nltk, k-means

I am using scikit learn's Kmeans algorithm to cluster comments.

```
sentence_list=['hello how are you', "I am doing great", "my name is abc"]

vectorizer=TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, max_df=0.9, stop_words='english', decode_error='ignore')
vectorized=vectorizer.fit_transform(sentence_list)

km=KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, init='k-means++',n_init=10, verbose=1)
km.fit(vectorized)
```

when i print the output of vectorized, it gives me the index of the words and the tf-idf scores of the index.

So im wondering, given we only get the tfidf scores of words, how is it that we manage to cluster documents based on individual words and not the score of an entire document? Or maybe it does this..Can someone explain to me the concept behind this?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  The process of splitting the text into words is part of the vectorization/fitting process.

Comment: my ultimate goal is to be able to plot a 2d graph with y axis being tfidf scores and x-axis maybe being the count vector (or something else that makes more sense) and each data point is 1 document. So i was curious to know if the score for each sentence is actually computed behind the scene such that clusters with the most similar scores are clustered together?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should take a look at how the [Kmeans algorithm](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#k-means) works. First the stop words never make it to `vectorized`, therefore are totally ignored by Kmeans and don't have any influence in how the documents are clustered. Now suppose you have:

```
sentence_list=["word1", "word2", "word2 word3"]
```

Lets say you want 2 clusters. In this case you expect the second and the third document to be in the same cluster because they share a common word. Lets see how this happens.

The numeric representation of the docs `vectorized` looks like:

```
word1     word3     word2
    1  0.000000  0.000000     # doc 1
    0  1.000000  0.000000     # doc 2
    0  0.605349  0.795961     # doc 3
```

In the first step of Kmeans, some centroids are **randomly** chosen from the data, for example, the document 1 and the document 3 will be the initial centroids:

```
Centroid 1:     [1, 0.000000, 0.000000]

Centroid 2:     [0, 0.605349, 0.795961]
```

Now if you calculate the distances from every point(document) to each one of the two centroids, you will see that:

- document 1 has distance 0 to centroid 1 so it belongs to centroid 1
- document 3 has distance 0 to centroid 2 so it belongs to centroid 2

Finally we calculate the distance between the remaining document 2 and each centroid to find out which one it belongs to:

```
>>> from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

>>> euclidean([0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0])               # dist(doc2, centroid1)
1.4142135623730951

>>> euclidean([0, 1, 0], [0, 0.605349, 0.795961]) # dist(doc2, centroid2)
0.8884272507056005
```

So the 2nd document and the second centroid are closer, this means that the second document is assigned to the 2nd centroid.

Comment: Is it possible to plot each document on a 2d axis to have a visual representation to give us a better idea of how many clusters we should have or where the centroid should be?

Comment: I have never done this on whole documents but I don't see a problem with your idea. I think it should be doable.

Comment: If we want to predict a new document now, how can the centroid be chosen from second cluster since it has two documents(1 and 3)?

Comment: How are the results plotted on the graph? For higher dimensional data. I have implemented clustering on documents what i want to do is plot the results. @elyase

Answer (score 1):

TF/IDF is a measure that calculates the importance of a word in a document with respect to the rest of the words in that document. It does not compute the importance of a standalone word. (and it makes sense, right? Because importance always means priviledge over others!). So TF/IDF of each word is actually an importance measure of a document with respect to the word.

I don't see where TF/IDF is used in your code. However, it is possible to compute the kmeans algorithm with TF/IDF scores used as features. Also, clustering for the three sample documents that you have mentioned is simply impossible, while no two documents there have a common word!

**Edit 1:**  First of all, if the word 'cat' occurs in two documents it is possible that they would be clustered together (depending on other words in the two documents and also other documents). Secondly, you should learn more about k-means. You see, kmeans uses features to cluster documents together, and each tf/idf score for each word in a document is a feature measure that's been used to compare that document against others on a corpus.

Comment: Those are just examples, so if in 2 of my sentence, the word 'cat' exists, will the 2 sentences with 'cat' be clustered together based on that since the other words are stopwords? And if that is the case, does the algo compute a score for each sentence based on the tfidf of each word in a document (assuming 'cat' has a high tfidf score)?

Comment: @jenn check out my first edit! let me know if you have further quetions.